# Can I configure the auto duplex feature of my Canon Pixma printer on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, pdf, printing

I am trying to configure a printer ([Canon Pixma mg3150](http://www.canon.co.uk/For_Home/Product_Finder/Multifunctionals/Inkjet/PIXMA_MG3150/)) to my mac... everything looks fine, I can print a page of 1 side. The specification of the printer shows `auto duplex print`, but the `Two Sided` is not permitted from the PDF viewer as follows:

Does anyone know if the printer really permits auto duplex print?

[image]

Comment: The obvious questions: does duplex printing work in other programs? Do you have the latest drivers? Did you try different presets?

Comment: Is there a "Paper Handling" choice where we see "Layout" in your picture?

Comment: Indeed, there is a choice `Duplex Printing & Margin` which responds to my need, thank you very much...

Answer (score 1):

Go into the system preferences, Print & Scan, click on the printer, and click "Options & Supplies...".  Under the "Driver" tab, check and see if there's some sort of option to turn a duplexer on & off.

Answer (score 0):

Two-side printer setting is located under "Duplex Printing & Margins".

Comment: No, I think there should be a checkbox labeled "two-sided" next to the copies field.

Comment: Canon printers seem to have duplex printer options working only under "Duplex Printing & Margins".  This suggestion appears to have worked for SoftTimur.